# iPhone development with an Intel GMA 950

Tags: iphone

I am thinking about purchasing a used MacBook with an Intel GMA 950 graphics card for iPhone application development.

Will this card present any problems?

So far I have only been able to find this thread: http://forum.unity3d.com/viewtopic.php?t=17454 but I don't have enough experience to understand what they are talking about.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the thread you posted.

> A MacMini will serve you very well for iPhone development with the one exception that it cannot ***compute occlusion culling information***. AFAIK that fact will not change in any coming updates/releases on our end.

Occlusion culling is when an object is behind other opaque objects, then it may be culled.

From Wikipedia:

> This is a very popular mechanism to speed up the rendering of large scenes that have a moderate to high depth complexity

[More detail on Occlusion Culling.](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~zhangh/hom.html)

Answer (score 2):

Are you going to be developing 3D iPhone applications? If not, there will certainly be no problem.

If so, I'll leave it to others with more experience to answer.

Comment: Nope, no 3d apps in the near future. Thanks for the help.